# Determine library name of object variable in VBA 2007..?

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-word, vba

How can the fully qualified class and member name of an object variable be determined in VBA 2007..? For instance, `Excel.Range` rather than just `Range`...just as it appears in code?

Both Excel and Word have a `Range` object, but they are vastly different classes. In the example below, a `Range` is passed to the function. How can the function determine which class it's from..?

The results of the example produce "Microsoft Excel.Range". Although that's close, it's not the same. But Parent.Name and the class name are two different properties, and in other software they could be totally different text strings with no commonality.

So...how can one get `Excel.Range` instead of `Microsoft Excel.Range`..?

```
'Note: Project has references to both Excel and Word.
Public Sub Demo()
    Dim r As Excel.range
    Dim fulltype As String
    Set r = ActiveCell
    fulltype = WhatAmI(r)
    Debug.Print fulltype
    Select Case fulltype
        Case "Excel.Range"
            'Do stuff.
        Case "Word.Range"
            'Do other stuff.
    End Select
End Sub

Private Function WhatAmI(ByRef X As Object) As String
    Dim typ As String
    Dim par As String
    typ = TypeName(X)
    par = X.Application.Parent.Name
    WhatAmI = par & "." & typ
End Function
```

Comment: Why is "Microsoft Excel" not enough?  It is fixed, simply map it to "Excel" in your logic.

Comment: If you want the logic to be broadly applicable, you can't use the `.Application` property, since many objects don't posses that property. For this case it will do, though, but testing a random object with that function risks a run-time error.

Comment: Oh, and if you're really set on determining the parent object, you might want to read [this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2016/03/24/a-reflection-on-vba-reflection/). Luckily, it's writer is active here on SO and often checks the VBA tag. Unfortunately, VBA doesn't support reflection by default.

Comment: @SMeaden...that's an excellent point. I suppose I had me head wrapped around too many details, but it should work.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I was going to account for that with an error handler. My code examples were highly trimmed down to focus on the topic. Also, I need to look at RubberDuck's goodies again. I seem to lean towards advanced VB, and his stuff has come up before but I never sat down to get acquainted with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use TypeOf to test if an object implements a specific interface:

```
Public Sub Demo()
    Dim r As Excel.range
    Dim fulltype As String
    Set r = ActiveCell
    If TypeOf r Is Excel.Range Then

    ElseIf TypeOf r Is Word.Range Then

    End If
End Sub
```

If an object implements a specific interface, it's (somewhat) safe to use the associated methods and properties.

Note that a single object can implement many interfaces, consider the following Access example:

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM MSysObjects")
Debug.Print TypeOf rs Is Object
'True
Debug.Print TypeOf rs Is Recordset
'True
Debug.Print TypeOf rs Is Recordset2
'True
Debug.Print TypeOf rs Is DAO.Recordset
'True
Debug.Print TypeOf rs Is DAO.Recordset2
'True
Debug.Print TypeOf rs Is ADODB.Recordset
'False
```

Comment: Just FYI, `TypeOf` tests if an object variable implements a specified interface, rather than determining its actual object type.

Comment: @Rory True, but it'll differentiate between those types, and if it passes the test you can use the relevant properties and methods. That's often exactly what you need to know when developing a library that can work with multiple types of objects.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to clarify that point, since it doesn't strictly do what was *asked for*, even if it does what was *required*. ;)

Comment: True, I've reworded my answer to reflect that. Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: Unfortunately, unless I'm mistaken or missing something, the TypeOf operator is a .Net resident, and not present in VBA. Or if it is in newer version of VBA, it's not in 2007.

Comment: @spinjector That's not true. TypeOf is present by default in VBA. I don't know for certain it's present in Office 2007, but I've used it in Office 2010 and onwards, without any external references. Unfortunately, I can't find the documentation, so I can't verify when it was introduced.

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. I searched the help file and it kept showing me the help for If-Then and I thought the file was mis-linked. I just checked more carefully and sure enough, smack dab in the middle of the entry in fine print is the mention of TypeOf. And it's not listed elsewhere in the Operators section. I can't recall the last time I looked at the entry for If-Then, and I've obviously disadvantaged myself. Thanks for showing me the error of my oversight. =-)

Comment: Np, I'm here to answer questions :). Hope you can put it to good use.

Comment: Anywho...in fact I think the TypeOf operator is exactly what I need. In fact, it will work better than looking at the text strings for Name, Fullname, Parent, etc. I think this because it tests precisely against the class and member using whatever method VBA uses to know for instance, the difference between Excel.Range and Word.Range. In the end, I think I don't even need to know the actual names of the class & member, I just need to branch the code properly. Thanks again..!